# Movieclip to spawn in a set parameter

Tags: actionscript-3, random, movieclip

I like to make a movieclip randomly spawn in a set area. But theres a little more to it, usually you'd have something like the X pos set to something like 250 (say the centre) and the Y pos set to be `math.random` but it won't work for how I'd like it.

I'm making a First Person Shooter and want the `Enemy movieclip` to spawn off stage but from the Top, Bottom, Left and Right of the stage as shown in the quick annotated image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dpCw.png).

Is this possible to be done? If so how could I achive this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Something dirty like this would work

```
_enemy.x = _enemy.y = 0;
while(_enemy.x >= 0 && _enemy.x <= stage.stageWidth)
{
    _enemy.x = Math.random() * (stage.stageWidth * 3) - stage.stageWidth;
}
while(_enemy.y >= 0 && _enemy.y <= stage.stageHeight)
{
    _enemy.y = Math.random() * (stage.stageHeight * 3) - stage.stageHeight;
}
```

Or you could go for a more fancy approach, where enemies would spawn with a random angle on a circles edge. The enemies will always be spawned at a fixed distance from the stage's center, but this can easily be modified

```
var radius:Number = 800: // Set this to be greater than stage dimensions
var angle:Number  = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
_enemy.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) + ( Math.cos( angle ) * radius );
_enemy.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2) + ( Math.sin( angle ) * radius );
```

Comment: This dose look dirty :) Thanks, I'm a bit busy at the moment but will implement it later and let you know how I get on with it.

Comment: I'd go with the second approach; sure the code is (negligibly) slower, but it's cleaner and you have the neat feature to set the distance of the spawn point from the stage center. I edited the second example to adjust for the stage center, which I forgot.

Comment: @stalem I don't see why the `while` loops are necessary.

Comment: Because the code that sets the enemy position within the while handlers, can still provide a value that is within the stage borders. So the while handlers checks if they're within stage bounds, and if so, randomize a new position.